How to open Google Account settings programmatically from an Android app?

Tried this:
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setClassName(
            "com.google.android.gms",
            "com.google.android.gms.settings.GoogleAccountSettingsActivity"
        )
        startActivity(intent)

But it does not work (throws "could not find activity...")
